# Count number PHP +1

Tags: php, html, laravel, count

I have database like this:

```
id     menuname   parent_id
-----+----------+-----------
 1     a            0
 2     b            0
 10    a/xx         1
 11    a/xo         1
 20    b/xx         2
 21    b/xx         2
```

I only have the first two lines for the parent menu id. I get the number 1 and 2. How do I make the sub menu ID from the `parent_id`.

ID 10 is from `parent_id` 1 and 0
ID 11 is from `parent_id` 1 and 1
ID 20 is from `parent_id` 2 and 0
ID 21 is from `parent_id` 2 and 1

I want to make it as a form in php

- First is a dropdown foreach and the value is ID with `parent_id=0` (1 and 2)
- Second is readonly text that contains the submenu ID (automatically becomes 10 or 11 or 12 or 13)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well you just need this

```
SELECT t2.* FROM table_name t1
  JOIN table_name t2 ON t1.id = t2.parentId
  WHERE t1.id = (1 or 2 or whatever ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply execute the SQL Syntax using order by.

```
SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY parent_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to make loop on initial values

```
foreach($parentValues as $eachValue){ // $parentValues will contain 1 and 2 loop first for 1
   // Fetch from database against column parent_id for $eachValue First value is 1 and against which user will get 10 and 11
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you are trying to do, you need to first get all the rows from the database. I would order by `menuname` so that they are in a nice order in the select menu later.

**SQL (basic concept)**

```
SELECT id, menuname, parent_id
FROM table_name
ORDER BY menuname
```

**PHP**

```
$result = //... Array of data from the SQL
$menu = [];

foreach ($result as $item) {
    $parentId = $item['parent_id'];
    if ($parentId > 0) {
        $menu[$parentId]['children'][] = $item;
    } else {
        $menu[$parentId] = $item;
    }
}
```

This should give you a nice array of menu items which you can loop through in your HTML to output the menus. If you want the menus to be chained when you select the parent to show the child options in the next menu, you need to use JavaScript to do so.